# Laravel 5 blade template Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I did a search and I want to display the result, but I cannot convey the variable to the view,
although I specify it in the controller.

My piece of view code:

```
<div class="search col-md-6">
    <p>
        Найти сотрудника по id
    </p>
    <form action="{{route('searchID')}}" class="search-id" method="GET">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="id" required="" type="text" value="{{ old('id') }}">
                    </input>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Искать">
                    </input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{$result}}
    </form>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my route:

```
 Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'searchID', 'SearchController@indexID')->name('searchID');
```

my method in the controller:

```
public function indexID(Request $request, View $view)
{
    //$message= "Сотрудник не найден";
    $id = $request->input('id');
    dump($id);
    $result = Staff::where('public_id', $id)->get();

    if ($result == null) {
        //dump($message);
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($id);
    } else {
        dump($result);
        return view('addworker')->with('result', $result);
    }
}
```

But I constantly get an error: **Undefined variable: result**

I tried:

```
return view('addworker')->with($result);
```

and

```
return view('addworker',$result);
```

and

```
return view('addworker', ['result', $result]);
```

*None of this helped me, I don't know what to do anymore*

How to make the template access this variable only after the controller has been processed?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what I understand is that my balde is trying to understand what kind of variable I have specified before I try to submit the form, how to make the template access this variable only after the controller has been processed? It is in the controller that I create this variable.

Comment: The view will only access this variable after will return it, if you dont return the view with the variable, you can not access it

Comment: @LucasPiazzi got it. Because of this, I have the error. most likely I need to pass the variable visualization through the controller itself.But this did not work for me either, the view was unchanged. I used something like this:             `return view('addworker', $result)->render();`

Answer (score 3):

You can use compact for the same,

```
return view('addworker', compact('result'));
```

[compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) — Create array containing variables and their values

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you

```
return view('addworker', ['result' => $result]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You used the wrong syntax to send your variable to your view, there is a lot os ways to do that:

You could use the [compact](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.compact.php) function:

```
return view('addworker', compact('result'));
```

You could use the with() method:

```
return view('addworker')->with('result', $result);
```

Or:

```
return view('addworker', ['result' => $result]);
```

You could also check the official documentation: [click here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views)